# Can I change the layout of this SQL Query's output?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this SQL query,

```sql
SELECT wp_tq77_posts.`ID`,
       wp_tq77_posts.`post_date`,
       wp_tq77_users.`display_name`,
       wp_tq77_users.`user_email`,
       wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_name`,
       wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.`meta_value`
FROM wp_tq77_users
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_postmeta
     ON wp_tq77_postmeta.`meta_key` LIKE '_customer_user'
     AND wp_tq77_users.`ID` = wp_tq77_postmeta.`meta_value`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_posts
     ON wp_tq77_postmeta.`post_id` = wp_tq77_posts.`ID`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items
     ON wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_type` LIKE 'line_item'
     AND wp_tq77_posts.`ID` = wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
     ON wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.`meta_key` REGEXP 'Date|_line_total'
     AND wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_id` = wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.`order_item_id`
```

I get this output from phpMyAdmin:

[image: A table of order information]

The problem is that every individual order (you can tell by its ID) is being output twice. The only difference between each pair of orders is that the final column (meta_value) has either a number or a date.

This is happening because the number and date are both stored in "woocommerce_order_itemmeta.`meta_value`". That area of the database looks something like this:

Order ID --- Meta_Key  --- Meta_Value

200123 --- quantity --- 2
200123 --- _line_total --- 350
200123 --- Date --- April 3, 2018
200124 --- quantity --- 3
200124 --- _line_total --- etc.

The type of data in meta_value can only be distinguished using the meta_key. The meta key associated with the number mentioned above is "_line_total", and the meta key for the date is "Date".

I want to pull data from "order_itemmeta.`meta_value`" if and only if that data's meta key is either "Date" or "_line_total", and then I want to join that data to the rest of the output so that each unique order has only one row with 7 separate columns for ID, post_date, display_name, user_email, order_item_name, Date, and _line_total.

I am inexperienced with SQL and the query above was almost completely auto-generated using the Wordpress plugin wpDatatables. My only edit was changing the end of the second to last line from " LIKE 'Date' " to " REGEXP 'Date|_line_total' " in an attempt to select entries that had either "Date" or "_line_total" as their meta key.

**Is there any way to modify this query so that the "Date" and "_line_total" values no longer take up two rows but instead each have their own column in a single row?**

Thank you for reading this long post.

Comment: No. I don't see. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can, but we'll need to understand the structure of the item meta data table and how it relates to the rest of the data. See @Strawberry's link. Edit your question with the suggested additional detail.

Comment: None of the columns in your table match what you have called them in the actual question. I recommend that you use a consistent name for each column, so that we know what you want and how to help you.

Comment: I tried to describe the situation and problem a little better. Sorry for before.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow all this, but it seems you have an "OR" function for your last column. Try this:

```
SELECT wp_tq77_posts.`ID`,
       wp_tq77_posts.`post_date`,
       wp_tq77_users.`display_name`,
       wp_tq77_users.`user_email`,
       wp_tq77_postmeta.`meta_value`,
       wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_name`,
       metatotal.`meta_value` as line_total,
       metadate.`meta_value` as order_date

FROM wp_tq77_users
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_postmeta
     ON wp_tq77_postmeta.`meta_key` LIKE '_customer_user'
     AND wp_tq77_users.`ID` = wp_tq77_postmeta.`meta_value`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_posts
     ON wp_tq77_postmeta.`post_id` = wp_tq77_posts.`ID`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items
     ON wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_type` LIKE 'line_item'
     AND wp_tq77_posts.`ID` = wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as metatotal
     ON metatotal.`meta_key` LIKE 'line_total'
     AND wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_id` = metatotal.`order_item_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as metadate
     ON metatotal.`meta_key` LIKE 'Date'
     wp_tq77_woocommerce_order_items.`order_item_id` =
     metatotal.`order_item_id`
```

Again, I have no way of testing without a minimal, reproducible sample of your data. Also, it would be good to use a few aliases to make your query easier to follow. I made no attempt to clean up the query, just to solve your issue.